# converting jpg to mpg fails in convert/imagemagick

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, imagemagick

I'm running Imagemagick on CentOS 7, converting a directory of .jpg files to an mpg file and getting this error

convert -delay 5 fileprefix*.jpg -quality 80 test.mpg

convert: delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i "%M%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install ffmpeg](http://itekblog.com/ffmpeg-centos-7-installation-instructions/) and reinstall imagemagick. FFMpeg is required to create videos and you error means that Imagemagick fails to invoke it when "delegating" the task...

Comment: I installed ffmpeg and am still getting this error:  `Converting /www/webroot/cam/archive1/ar1*.jpg to  mpeg [public]
convert: delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i "%M%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065.`

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i 'fileprefix*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4` work?

Comment: Reinstall imagemagick to make it work together

Comment: I did `yum reinstall ImageMagick` and it did not make the problem go away.

executing the ffmpeg command specified did work and make a working mp4 file though.     I guess ImageMagick doesn't know where ffmpeg is?

Comment: Yes, you should create ffmpeg symlink in /usr/sbin so everything would be able to use ffmpeg: `ln -s /opt/path/to/ffmpeg  /usr/sbin/ffmpeg `